# soft referential integrity in teradata

Tags: foreign-keys, teradata

I am trying to define a referential integrity constraint in TD. But its throwing the following error.

```
alter table table_name 
    add constraint FK_site_part 
    foreign key (Oem_Site_Cd,Oem_Part_Nr) 
    references with no check option 2ndtabe_name (Site_Cd,Oem_Part_Nr);
```

```
 *** Failure 3976 Incorrect referential constraint definition.
                Statement# 1, Info =0
 *** Total elapsed time was 1 second.`
```

could you please help me out with it. Moreover these tables do not have UPI defined, is that the reason for the above error.

Answer (score 0):

The parent columns `2ndtabe_name` must have the same column definition as the child columns in `table_name`. Uniqueness is not a requirement for referential constraints (soft-ri) in Teradata.

Have you verified the column definitions are consistent? Are there other RI constraints defined amongst these two tables? Can you post table definitions?